# Train on top of a Torchscript model

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

I currently have a Torchscript model I load via `torch.jit.load`. I would like to take some data I have and train on top of these weights, however I cannot find out how to train a serialised torchscript model.

Comment: Torchscript main purpose is to run models in production environments in inference mode. It is not designed for training networks, you should use the Pytorch code you used for training instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that code

Comment: Did you try using the model with standard Python training loop? According to [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17614) it should be fine as it subclasses `torch.nn.Module`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the returned `ScriptModule` does actually support training: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.jit.ScriptModule.html#torch.jit.ScriptModule.train